# Über die Wendung "jemandem zu schaffen machen"

Tags: grammatical-case

> Was **ihr** dabei am meisten zu schaffen macht, erklärt die Jobberaterin in einer neuen Folge von "Wie ich euch sehe".

Warum verwendet man die Wendung "jemandem zu schaffen machen" mit dem Dativ? Immerhin verwendet man das Verb machen mit dem Akkusativ. Oder liegt es daran, dass ursprünglich die Wendung noch einen Teil hatte, der im Akkusativ stand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In vielen Sprachen (z.B. im Englischen) wird der Dativ sehr "wörtlich" genommen und bezeichnet nur noch einen möglichen Fall: Den Empfänger von etwas, "das gegeben wird", also die quasi wörtliche Bedeutung von "Dativ".

Im Deutschen wird der Dativ noch (analog zu Latein) für sehr viel mehr Zwecke verwendet. Dein Beispiel ist ein *dativus commodi* (bzw. hier eher *incommodi*) und bezeichnet, zu wessen Vor- bzw. (hier) Nachteil etwas geschieht.

> Ich mache ihm Freude

Hier ist "ihm" der Nutznießer der Aktion und steht deswegen im Dativ. In deinem Beispiel ist "ihr" die Person, zu deren Nachteil etwas geschieht, also auch Dativ.

Comment: Der Nutznießer ist aber auch der Empfänger des Nutzens

Comment: Sehr schöne Erklärung (kommod auch weil brevis), jedoch gefällt mir das Kaffeebeispiel nicht. Da der Kaffee ja ein Ding ist, das dann (im Anschluss ans Gemachtwerden) gegeben wird und weil das Kaffeemachen sozialtypisch ja auch das Kaffeebringen einschließt, wäre ja dies ein Beispiel für den langweiligen Standardfall von Dativ, den auch ein Engländer noch nachvollziehen könnte. Finden wir kein besseres Beispiel für bunte Dativverwendung?

Comment: Mach aus "Kaffee" "Sorgen". Und wer Sorgen hat, hat auch Likör. Wenn du keinen Likör magst, nimm "Umstände". Im übrigen würde ein Engländer "Ich mache ihm Kaffee" nicht als indirektes Objekt (also für ihn, Standard-Dativ-Objekt) sehen - "He makes him coffee" funktioniert ja nicht, weil grade "make" im Englischen kein indirektes Objekt mag.

Comment: Hmhm. Dazu passt: "Jemandem zu schaffen machen" duldet auch kein (Akkusativ-) Objekt, auch wenn in den Kommentaren zur anderen Antwort hier heftig über Akkusativobjekte von "zu schaffen machen" debattiert wird. Das "zu schaffen" (ein verbaler Ausdruck für Arbeit, Mühe, Sorgen, Last) ist ja schon quasi das "direkte Objekt" des "Machens" hier.

Answer (score 1):

Bsp.: "Er macht jemandem/ihr etwas zu schaffen."

"Wem" etwas zu schaffen machen? -> jemandem,ihr (indirektes Objekt, der Empfänger, Dativ)

"Was" machen? -> zu schaffen (= Mühe, direktes Objekt, Akkusativ, "Wen" wäre z.B. "den Teufel")

"Wer" macht etwas zu schaffen? - Er (Subjekt, Nominativ)

Comment: Und gibt es Fälle, in denen das direkte Objekt zum Vorschein kommt?

Comment: Ich wiederhole es gerne und ständig: Die Begriffe "direktes" und "indirektes Objekt" passen im Deutschen nicht gut als Unterschiedung zwischen Akkusativ- und Dativobjekt und sollten besser nicht verwendet werden.

Comment: "*Etwas* macht mir zu schaffen" ist kein Akkusativ, sondern Nominativ! Und kein Objekt, sondern Subjekt. Du fragst ja sogar "wer oder was?"

Comment: Da ist kein Akkusativ, beim besten Willen nicht.

Comment: @äöü   In "Der tofro macht mir **etwas** zu schaffen" ist *etwas* kein Objekt und darum auch nicht im Akkusativ. Es ist eine Ergänzung der Art und Weise: *etwas* im Gegensatz zu *ganz schön* oder *ungeheuer* oder auch *einen ganzen halben Tag lang*. Nennt man so was eine adverbiale Bestimmung oder so?

Comment: Danke für die Tipps. Ja, ich hatte einen Denkfehler. "Zu schaffen" steht für das, worum sich "machen" dreht, also unser (Pseudo-)Akkusativ-Objekt.